# Callback doesn't update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The below function handle uploaded files, for some reason the `setFiles` doesn't update the `files` list after the callback ends so it causes the previous uploaded file to show up on the page, for example the user uploaded an image `1.jpg`, nothing will show up on the page, next the user uploads a second file- now the first image `1.jpg` will show up, and so on.

On `setFiles` the state is correct and updated but the `return` doesn't update the `files` state.

Any idea why?

```
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([])

  const addFiles = addedFiles => {
    const newFiles = Array.from(addedFiles, file => newFileDecorator(file))
    setFiles([...files, ...newFiles])

    newFiles.forEach(file => {
      file.reader.onload = async () => {
        const dimensions = await getImageDimensions(file.reader.result)
        setFiles(state => {
          const index = state.findIndex(f => f.id === file.id)
          state[index].readyState = file.reader.readyState
          state[index].dimensions = dimensions
          return state
        })
      }

      file.reader.readAsDataURL(file.data)
    })
  }
```

Comment: A couple of things, why are you updating `newFiles` after updating state with `setFiles`. You're also doing a state-mutation in your second call of `setFiles`

Comment: @ChristopherNgo He is not directly updating new files, he is attaching an event handler which updates state when the event fires later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mutating state without creating a new reference for it, so React skips the update as the shallow comparison indicates that they are the same object. Use this pattern instead.

```
       setFiles(state => {
          const file = state.find(f => f.id === file.id)
          file.readyState = file.reader.readyState
          file.dimensions = dimensions
          return [ ...state, file ]
        })
```